# 'Execute SQL String' - IndexError - list index out of range error

Tags: sql, postgresql, robotframework

I've the following sql generated when running the robotframework script - to insert some values into a postgres db.

```
INSERT INTO my_table(
    claim_no,
    patient_name,
    tpa,
    state,
    patient_id,
    national_id,
    claim_date,
    process_date,
    cheif_complaints,
    significant_signs,
    uuid
)
VALUES(
    'xxx',
    'xx xx xx xx',
    'xx xx',
    'CONFIRMED',
    '1035188',
    2294751132,
    TO_DATE('13/12/2023', 'DD/MM/YYYY'),
    now(),
    'xx xxx xx  F/U - GRBS 250 Mg %',
    'CHEST- CLEAR  HEART --S1-S2-0  ',
    '1cf4ad85-906b-4721-ab2d-95e26ed42778'
);
```

When running this, it's giving the error
`IndexError: list index out of range`

(There's a % symbol in one of the values, but it's inside single quotes.)

May I know the reason for this?
Thanks.

Comment: My only guesses is the "--" is causing a problem.  Somehow tricking the code to think its a comment.  A way to figure out the problem is to replace each value with a blank or 0 and manually executing it, to identify the erroring column.

Comment: I see three occurrences of two spaces in a row: `'xx xxx xx  F/U - GRBS 250 Mg %'`, `CLEAR  HEART,` and `S2-0  '`.  It is not clear how the query is passed to the keyword in your case, so, just in case, here is a reminder that two spaces have special meanings as separators in Robot Framework.

Comment: I am not a postgres db expert, but I see nothing wrong with the statement itself. My guess is that the error is either coming from logic that is building and preparing the statement, or coming from a trigger or someother background process that is running against the inserted data - possibly as part of a lookup or validation action.

Comment: The values are taken from another DB, where it has some entries added by the users, like  cheif_complaints and significant_signs. I have recently replaced all newlines with a \n. Will check for the two spaces now.
Thanks for all for the inputs.

Comment: The exception `IndexError` is a python one, and as there's no issue with the SQL statement itself (at least on the surface), it should be something in your surround code. Please add the RobotFramework code you are using to execute it - the problem can be in it.

Comment: Finally I got it working.

The error_message field is getting value from a json response and that % symbol need to be replaced - eventhough it's inside quotes. When I tested it on an Ubuntu, I couldn't reproduce the error. It happens when I run it on a Windows machine

Comment: @art - It sounds like this is not a case of bad data being passed to or from the database, but a case where a string having unknown (untrusted) content is being passed into a string formatting function, possibly as part of a write to log function. In other words, if you had a function `printf(format, value1, value2, ...)`, you should not pass untrusted data in as the first parameter `printf(response)`. Instead pass a format string and the data as separate parameters `printf("%s", response)`.  (I am using `printf` as a generic example. There are many functions out there that behave similarly.)